# ValueGeneratedOnAdd() or ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate() ro do nothing on an update

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a property/column titled Created that is set to GetUtcDate() on an insert. The insert works fine.

I want nothing to happen on an update. The value should be left alone. I think that means I should use ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate() because what that method is really saying is not that a vlaue is necessarily generated, but that EF should not set that value.

Is that correct? I ask because everything I find via search talks about setting a value via a trigger or other operation on an update. Nothing talks about leaving it alone. I want to verify that EF is fine with no action on the column on an update.

Comment: You can use **ValueGeneratedOnAdd()**.  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder-1.valuegeneratedonadd?view=efcore-7.0

Comment: @Soheil But then what happens on an update - will it overwrite with the value in the model object?

Answer (score 0):

As @Soheil said use the `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`, and code your entity in such a way that it doesn't allow the `Created` property to be changed in-memory.

In that case, the value of the property will be initially set when an entity is first saved into the database.

In future, when you read that entity from the database, it will have the value which is in the database, which is the initial value.

To make sure the value doesn't change, protect your property with a private setter and don't allow any methods to change it.

Then when you update the entity in-memory and want to save it back to the database, the `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` will not trigger, because it only triggers when a new entity is being saved, and the EntityFramework will detect no change in your property `Created` and as such won't update its value in the database.

Addendum:

For that particular usecase, it is excessive to use `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` to set an initial value, unless you really need the time when the entity was SAVED to the database, and precisely to the nanosecond.

I'm guessing you just want the `Created` property to hold the DateTime at which the system created the entity.

In that case, you can just do it like this inside the entity:

```cs
namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public class User
    {
        // Properties
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        
        // Constructors
        public User(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            }
            Name = name;

            CreationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
        /// <summary>Constructor for EntityFrameworkCore.</summary>
        /// <remarks>EntityFrameworkCore chooses the constructor with the least amount of parameters (including 0) where all of them correspond to a property.</remarks>
        private User() { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    }
}
```

The first public constructor is for your code to use to create the entity.

The second private constructor is for the EntityFramework to be able to create the entity when reading it from the database. It fills the property values using reflection after creating it.

Comment: I'd like to avoid it being set in all cases. Because in an ASP.NET app often the model object is not tracked and an Update() call says to write every property. Also, there should be a way to do this without disabling CS8618.

Comment: @DavidThielen The answer I wrote does what you want and answers your comment, please try to read it again and ask a follow up question if needed. The CS8618 is disabled only for the private constructor, because we know that EF is going to fill in the value of the `string Name` property after calling that constructor, but the compiler doesn't, and it doesn't effect anything.

Comment: I believe your solution will write to the column on an update. Granted, it is writing back the value already there, but it is overwriting it. I'd like to have a solution that does not overwrite. On the disable issue, I believe that can be avoided by providing a protected constructor that takes the values that are "private set."